# How can I use CSS for specific character code?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply CSS styles to the &#8226 (bullet) character but haven't found out how. Here's what I tried:

```
&#8226; {
    word-spacing: 1em;
}
```

Can something like this be done? Thanks

Comment: No, something like that cannot be done. CSS rules can only be applied to elements (and pseudo-elements).

Comment: No way, you can style dom elements, but not specific characters. Just wrap your char, or you can style list elements your way.

Comment: Actually calling duplicate on this post is not true!!! how ever... you have an ansere an you can also style it by using after or before.
`<div>some text</div>` and css `div::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: red;
}`
see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/ewLh67gv/

Comment: you can also change the size with e.g. `font-size: 30px` see fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/ewLh67gv/3/

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to use the bullet point in a span like this:

```
<span class="custom-bullet">&#8226;</span>
```

and then make your changes on the class as shown:

```
.custom-bullet {
     word-spacing: 1em;
}
```